# Passing a generic as parameter to DateTime's constructor

Tags: c#, datetime, generics, calendar

As you know PCL doesn't support PersianCalendar or GregorianCalendar class, So I'm using generic to achieve that, In this case consumer can pass the Calendar to the class:

```
public class DateConvertor<TCalendar> where TCalendar : Calendar
{
        public DateConvertor()
        {
            this.CurentCalendar = Activator.CreateInstance<TCalendar>();
        }

        public TCalendar CurentCalendar
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public DateTime GetDate(string date)
        {
            //....
            var newDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0);
            return newDate;
        }
}
```

So I need pass a new instance of PersianCalendar to DateTime's constructor:

```
var newDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0, new PersianCalendar());
```

Now my question is that How can I do that? For example something like this:

```
var newDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0, CurentCalendar);
```

Can I pass a generic type as a parameter to DateTime's constructor?

**Update**:
It seems that DateTime class doesn't have that signature for accepting a new instance of Calendar in Portable Class Library:

```
public DateTime(
    int year,
    int month,
    int day,
    int hour,
    int minute,
    int second,
    Calendar calendar
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noted, `DateTime` doesn't have the constructor you want in the PCL. However, you can use [`Calendar.ToDateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c1445e1):

```
return CurrentCalendar.ToDateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0, 0);
```

As an aside, you could change your generic constraint to include `new()`, and just call the constructor:

```
public class DateConverter<TCalendar> where TCalendar : Calendar, new()
{
    public DateConverter()
    {
        this.CurrentCalendar = new TCalendar();
    }
}
```

Or use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project which supports other calendars in a rather more pleasant way, IMO - e.g. a `LocalDateTime` "knows" the calendar it belongs to, and allows you to convert to a `LocalDateTime` in another calendar, etc.